# SELECT a column whose value is "if Id exists in another table/view"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

This does what I want:

```
SELECT a.*,
    IIF(l.Id IS NOT NULL,
        CAST(1 AS BIT),
        CAST(0 AS BIT)) AS IsLatest
  FROM [A] a
  LEFT JOIN [LatestA] l on (l.Id = a.Id)
```

`LatestA` is a view that contains only the latest `A`'s.

However, I feel like the `IIF(..., TRUE, FALSE)` is silly. Is there a better way of testing for the existance of the `Id` in the `LatestA`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is fine. Some RDBMS have shortcuts to turn a the result of a predicate to a boolean value, but not SQL Server.

You can slightly simplify it as follows:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    CASE WHEN l.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsLatest
FROM [A] a
LEFT JOIN [LatestA] l on l.Id = a.Id
```

Note that I used a `CASE` expression instead of the `IIF()` function: I prefer it because it is standard SQL. I also find that it is simpler to use `IS NULL` rather than `IS NOT NULL` here.

If you *really* want to return a `BIT` for some reason, then:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    CAST(CASE WHEN l.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS IsLatest
FROM [A] a
LEFT JOIN [LatestA] l on l.Id = a.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL doesn't allow you to use boolean expressions as integer values (as MySQL does) because it has a third possible boolean value (`UNKNOWN`) so you are stuck with something like what you have. You can simplify it somewhat:

```
SELECT a.*,
       CAST(IIF(l.Id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS IsLatest
FROM [A] a
LEFT JOIN [LatestA] l on (l.Id = a.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use EXISTS operator, it's used to check the existence of a record

`if exists ([query for ID])
 BEGIN
 [Quert from another table]
 END`